# Check boxes checked?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, isset, checked

Now I've done a lot of research, tried a lot of methods in PHP, including $_POST isset..
foreach
 etc

But i need some help!

Basically, **just want to check if the checkboxes have been checked. And THEN, add 1 to the number of $visits made if the checkbox has been checked.**

As long as I can check if the checkbox is checked, i think i can figure it out from there!

Thanks in advance

( note: $visits is the number of times a property has been visited. This coding displays property information read from a file)

```
<?
    $filename = "house.txt";
    $filepointer = fopen($filename,"r");  // open for read
?>

<html>
<head>
    <h1> Search for properties</h1>
    <form method = "post" action= "visit.php">
        Enter max price
        <input type = "text" name = "max" value="<?=$Max;?>">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
        <br><i><p>Properties found</p></i></br>
    </form>
</head>
</html>

<?
    $myarray = file ($filename);
    for ($mycount = 0; $mycount < count($myarray); $mycount++ ) { // one input line at a time
        $aline = $myarray[$mycount];
        $postcode = getvalue($aline,0);
        $value = getvalue($aline,1);
        $image = getvalue ($aline,2);
        $visits = getvalue($aline,3);
        $Max = $_POST['max'];

        if ($value < $Max) {
            print "<table border = 2>";
            print "<FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION='visit.php' >";
            print "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='check' value='Yes' > $postcode </td><BR> \n";
            print "<td>$value <BR>";
            print "<td>$image<BR>";
            print "<td>$visits<BR><p>";
            print "</table>";
            print "</form>";
        }
    }

    function getvalue ($aline, $commaToLookFor) {   
        $intoarray = explode(",",$aline);
        return  $intoarray[ $commaToLookFor];  
    }

    if (isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'] == 'Yes') {
        echo "checked!";
    } else {
        echo "not checked!.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: So what's going wrong?

Comment: The last bit of the coding (which checks if the checkboxes are checked) does not work.

Comment: error: failure to ask question in post.

Comment: Apologies, check again. I do have a valid question

Comment: Does it print out "checked" or "not checked?"

Comment: Explosions - even if a checkbox is checked, it will output not checked"

Comment: Just check to see if it `isset`, don't check `== 'Yes'`

Comment: Hi Jon, Did that - but it always comes up as "not checked!"

Comment: Since it looks like you are creating multiple forms here - how do you submit it?  The submit button at the top is for a different form than any checkboxes that are on the page.

Comment: @ShaziaE, the check box will be submitted/`isset()==true` only if the checkbox has been checked.

Comment: @Jon - the first form searches through the house.txt file for relevant properties ... I just included a submit button at the end for the checkbox function but it still does not work..

Comment: @SheikhHeera - doesnt work unfortunately..

Comment: @ShaziaE, did you checked `if (isset($_POST['check']))` ?

Comment: So you have one submit button for every checkbox now?  Because if so, it's inefficient and won't convey much.  Open the form before the checkboxes, and then add a sumit button and close the form after them.

Comment: Jon is right; see my answer below - I just added a code example proving it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting a different form than the one you think you are...you have two forms on the page, both submitting to "visit.php". This line shouldn't exist:

`print "<FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION='visit.php' >";`

...since you've already created the form at the top of your file.

This will require a little reorganization of your code, but the basic idea is that you want one and only one form that contains all the fields and the submit button, otherwise you're submitting the form that contains the max price and nothing else.

Alternatively, if you actually do need separate forms (I'm not familiar enough with your use case to be sure), then the second form would need its own submit button.

Simplified working code:

```
 print "<table border = 2>";
print "<FORM METHOD='POST' ACTION='visit.php' >";
  print "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='check' value='Yes' > $postcode </td><BR> \n";
  print "<td> <button type='submit'>Submit</button> </td><BR> \n";
 print "</table>";
 print "</form>";

//personally I would just check for isset($_POST['check']), but it doesn't really matter... 
if (isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'] == 'Yes') 
{
  echo "checked!";
}
else
{
  echo "not checked!.";
}
```